# Monitor won't go into sleep mode automatically after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: monitor

After upgrading to 13.04 from Xubuntu 12.10, my monitor no longer goes to sleep automatically.  In Power Manager, On AC, Monitor, I have it set to put the display to sleep after 10 minutes off after 15, but the monitor stays on the whole time.  However, I can manually put the monitor in sleep mode by running `xset dpms force off`.  Any ideas?

*Edit:* On further investigation, even if I use `xset dpms force off`, the monitor switches back on after a 10-15 seconds, but the screensaver does not go off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off / remove xscreensaver:

```
sudo aptitude remove xscreensaver
```

Thanks to maestrobwh1 on Ubuntu Forums [for the answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162513).

Comment: Great, thanks Mark! This was driving me crazy for the past couple of days.